# Can't resolve paths from index.html after npm run build

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I run this command to build my project:

npm run build

but I cannot find `index.html` file and other `.js` files.

my `webpack.config.js` :

```
var path = require('path')
var webpack = require('webpack')
var AssetsPlugin = require('assets-webpack-plugin')
//var ExtractTextPlugin = require("extract-text-webpack-plugin");

var DEBUG = !(process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production')

if (DEBUG) {
  require('dotenv').config()
}

var config = {
  devtool: DEBUG ? 'cheap-module-eval-source-map' : false,
  entry: {
    app: ['./app/app'],
    vendor: [
      'react',
      'react-router',
      'redux',
      'react-dom',
      'lodash',
      'bluebird',
      'humps',
      'history'
    ]
  },
  resolve: {
    modules: [ path.join(__dirname, 'app'), 'node_modules' ]
  },
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: '[name].js'
  },
  plugins: [
    //new ExtractTextPlugin('styles.css'),
    new webpack.EnvironmentPlugin(['NODE_ENV', 'API_BASE_URL']),
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
      $: 'jquery',
      jQuery: 'jquery',
      'window.jQuery': 'jquery'
    })
  ],
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        include: __dirname
      },
      {
      //  test: /\.css$/,
        test:/\.(s*)css$/,
        use: [
          { loader: "style-loader" },
          { loader: "css-loader" }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}


if (DEBUG) {
  config.entry.app.push('webpack-hot-middleware/client?path=/__webpack_hmr')

  config.plugins = config.plugins.concat([
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
      name: 'vendor',
      filname: 'vendor.js'
    })
  ])
  config.output.publicPath = '/'
  config.module.rules.unshift({
    test: /\.js$/,
    loader: 'react-hot-loader',
    exclude: /node_modules/,
    include: __dirname
  })
} else {
  config.plugins = config.plugins.concat([
    new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
      name: 'vendor',
      filname: '[name].[chunkhash].js'
    }),
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin(),
  ])
}

module.exports = config
```

inside of `dist` directory:

[image]

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "universal-redux-template",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "description": "Universal Redux Template",
  "scripts": {
    "lint": "eslint app bin",
    "start": "cross-env NODE_PATH=./app concurrently --kill-others \"node app/server\" \"gulp css:watch\"",
    "test:prebuild": "./bin/test-prebuild",
    "test:watch": "yarn run test:prebuild; yarn run test:babelwatch",
    "test:babelwatch": "NODE_ENV=test babel app --out-dir .babel-test-build --source-maps --watch --ignore app/assets app/styles app/server  --skip-initial-build",
    "test": "./bin/test",
    "test:ci": "yarn run test:prebuild; yarn test",
    "webpack": "webpack",
    "build": "rimraf dist/ && npm run webpack && gulp build",
    "postinstall": "npm run build"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "6.1.0",
    "npm": "3.8.6"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "https://github.com/mz026/universal-redux-template"
  },
  "license": "MIT",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/mz026/universal-redux-template/issues"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "assets-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
    "babel-core": "^6.3.15",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.0",
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.3.14",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.3.13",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.3.13",
    "babel-register": "^6.5.1",
    "bluebird": "^2.10.0",
    "compression": "^1.6.0",
    "concurrently": "^2.0.0",
    "cross-env": "^1.0.7",
    "crypto-js": "^3.1.9-1",
    "easytimer.js": "^2.2.1",
    "ejs": "^2.3.4",
    "express": "^4.13.3",
    "gulp": "^3.9.0",
    "gulp-autoprefixer": "^3.1.0",
    "gulp-load-plugins": "^1.2.0",
    "gulp-rev": "^6.0.1",
    "gulp-rev-all": "^0.8.24",
    "gulp-rev-replace": "^0.4.3",
    "gulp-sass": "^2.1.1",
    "gulp-sourcemaps": "^1.6.0",
    "history": "^1.17.0",
    "humps": "^0.6.0",
    "immutable": "^3.8.1",
    "jalaali-js": "^1.1.0",
    "lodash": "^3.10.1",
    "node-sass": "^3.4.2",
    "normalizr": "^1.0.0",
    "owl.carousel": "^2.3.2",
    "prop-types": "^15.5.10",
    "react": "^15.4.2",
    "react-dom": "^15.4.2",
    "react-helmet": "^5.1.3",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.5",
    "react-router": "^3.0.5",
    "react-slick": "^0.22.3",
    "redux": "^3.0.0",
    "redux-logger": "^1.0.9",
    "redux-thunk": "^0.1.0",
    "rewire": "^2.3.4",
    "rimraf": "^2.5.2",
    "run-sequence": "^1.2.2",
    "slick-carousel": "^1.8.1",
    "superagent": "^1.8.5",
    "webpack": "^2.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-eslint": "^7.2.1",
    "babel-plugin-react-transform": "^2.0.0",
    "babel-plugin-rewire": "^1.0.0-beta-5",
    "chai": "^3.3.0",
    "chai-as-promised": "^5.1.0",
    "chokidar": "^1.6.1",
    "css-loader": "^0.28.11",
    "dotenv": "^4.0.0",
    "enzyme": "^2.3.0",
    "eslint": "^3.18.0",
    "eslint-plugin-babel": "^3.2.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^6.0.0",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.2",
    "jsdom": "^7.0.1",
    "md5-file": "^3.1.1",
    "mocha": "^2.4.5",
    "nock": "^2.17.0",
    "react-addons-test-utils": "^15.4.2",
    "react-hot-loader": "^1.3.1",
    "rewire-webpack": "^1.0.0",
    "sinon": "^1.17.1",
    "sinon-chai": "^2.8.0",
    "style-loader": "^0.20.3",
    "webpack-dev-middleware": "^1.10.2",
    "webpack-hot-middleware": "^2.18.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: What is your npm `build` script/command in your package.json ? Edit : and can you also add your HTML file in your question ?

Comment: updated my codes.

Comment: Which version of webpack are you using?

Comment: can you provide the error logs ? also your gulpfile would be really useful

Answer (score 0):

In case you are using Webpack 3, I think you are missing the HTML plugin

```
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin')

module.exports = {
  entry: 'index.js',
  output: {
    path: __dirname + '/dist',
    filename: 'index_bundle.js'
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin()
  ]
}
```

This will generate a file dist/index.html.